# How to update a column from one table if an update occurs on a column from a different table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. One table has a column named priority and the other table has priority date.
I want a trigger to update the priority date when the value in the priority column from the other table is updated.

Comment: OK sounds like a good plan.  What have you tried so far? Are you having a problem in trying to write your trigger?

Answer (score 0):

For reference, take a look at the trigger syntax in the [MySQL Reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html). Triggers work in MySQL Server 5.0.2 and higher.